# How to properly exit CAcroApp?

Tags: acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I referenced Acrobat.dll in a simple C# Console program, and then wrote a couple of lines of codes to run Acrobat.

```
CAcroApp mApp = new AcroAppClass();
Console.WriteLine("Acrobat is running");
bool bClose = mApp.CloseAllDocs();
bool bExit = mApp.Exit();
```

However, while CloseAllDocs() return true, Exit() always return false.

And accordingly I can still see Acrobat process running in the Task Manager.

However, once the program ends, the process also gets killed automatically.

How can I make it so that I can close Acrobat process from within the program without having to exit the program as well?

Answer (score 0):

From my experiance, the Acrobat process will close only when all related objects are garbage collected. To force collection, use the following code:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

Note: Garbage collection only works when the related objects (e.g. mApp) are no longer in scope.